# What do the %h and %p do in this command?

Tags: proxy, netcat

`$ ssh -o User=fred -o ProxyCommand="nc -X 5 -x localhost:9150 %h %p" server.example.org`

It's from http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

I can't find any comments about the `%h` and `%p` arguments.

Answer (score 7):

It's in the manpage, under the section for `ProxyCommand`:

> Specifies the command to use to connect to the server.  The command string extends to the end of the line, and is executed with
>   the user's shell.  In the command string, any occurrence of ‘%h’
>   will be substituted by the host name to connect, ‘%p’ by the
>   port, and ‘%r’ by the remote user name.

So in this case, `%h` will stand for `server.example.org` and `%p` will stand for `22`.

By the way, an easier way to spell `-o User=fred` is `-l fred`.

Comment: Thanks. What if I omit the `%h` and `%p` here? What would happen? Since the ssh itself has the `-P` argument already.

Comment: Well, if you omit the `%h` and `%p` then the `nc` command no longer makes sense because `nc` is expecting arguments there. So `nc` should give you an error.

Comment: Still not quite sure the `%p` meaning. For instance: `ssh -o ProxyCommand="nc -X 5 -x localhost:8888 %h %p" -P 61234` so for this command, the `-P 61234` specifies the port to be 61234 and what does `%p` mean then?

Comment: If you have `-P 61234` on the command line (or in a config file) then 61234 will be substituted for `%p` in the `ProxyCommand`, same as `server.example.org` gets substituted for `%h`. And if you had a `%r` in there then it would stand for `fred`.

Comment: @AwQiruiGuo The -P is for ssh and the %p is for nc. They both need to know the port.

Comment: Does that mean the it is the `ssh` command which was going to replace the placeholders and the final arguments which were passed to the `nc` command is the result after replacement?

Comment: @jayatubi I don't understand your question.